C# client (.NET 4.5) for image upload and a text string to ASP.NET Core Web API
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API to upload images to a gallery. It needs image upload and a user string at the end point. In swagger it works fine and shows a button for image upload and a text box to enter the user name.
The API endpoint is defined like this:
[HttpPost]
public List<Models.Image> PostUploadImage(IFormFile file, string user)
{
     if (_utility.IsValidImageFile(file))
     {
         string currentRootPath = _hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

         List<Models.Image> images = _utility.ObtainUploadedImages(file, user, currentRootPath);

         return images;
     }
     else
     {
         string error = $"{file} is not a valid image";
         var image = new Models.Image { Error = error };
         return [image];
     }
}

The API works fine using Swagger. My client is an ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.5) app. The following code works fine when the API was also .NET 4.5. The API is on another server. The client accesses the API over the network.
The client code is shown here:
string url = Constants.GetApiUrl() + "/mycontroller/" + user;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, Request.Content);

    List<Models.Image> images = new List<Models.Image>();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        images = JsonToModel(response.Content);
        return images;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response.StatusCode);
    }
}

Right now it breaks in the client with 405 error

StatusCode: 405,
ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed',
Version: 1.1,
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
Headers:
{
Date: Sun, 19 May 2024 16:00:37 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
Allow: GET
}

My question is how do I set up my URL and upload the image.
I tried to search all over the internet but only found how to upload images using .NET Core.
I would like to know how to set up a client using .NET 4.5 to access an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API for uploading an image and a text string.

Your API method doesn't have a specific URL defined, so it will be reachable at https://(host)/api/(controller)/PostUploadImage - but your .NET 4.5 code seems to try to post to an URL of https://(host)/mycontroller/{user} - are you sure you're posting to the correct URL ??

You are using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software

Thanks. I can include "using" but that won't solve my problem, though.

marc_s, So, my client will work if I post at the url https://(host)/api/(controller)/PostUploadImage/user? I will try it report back.

You can use swagger to check whether PostUploadImage method in ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API can correctly receive the post request. If the request can be received correctly, you can check whether the client URL is correct.

Yunning Dun. Yes, it works fine. As I said , there is nothing wrong with the API. the API works fine. My question is, how do I call it from another C# client to the end points.
